# TypeScript error: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2' ". Why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting a weird TypeScript error.

I have the following example:

```
interface Foo {
  prop: 0 | 1 | 2;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  prop = 1;
}
```

And I am getting the error:

```
src/example.ts:6:3 - error TS2416: Property 'prop' in type 'Bar' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Foo'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2'.

6   prop = 1;
    ~~~~
```

Why does this code give the error?

Comment: try `prop: 0 | 1 | 2 = 1`;

Comment: An [unsuccessful attempt was made](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118) to contextually type implementation/subclass properties by the types of their interface/superclass definitions.  It just doesn't happen unfortunately.  So the inferred type of `prop` in `Bar` is widened to `number`.  You have to hint the compiler to keep it narrow, like `prop = 1 as const` in TS3.4 or above, or `prop =1 as Foo['prop']`, or `readonly prop = 1` if you're not going to change it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

You can now also do the following (`readonly`, `as const`) if it fits your use case:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  readonly prop = 1;
}
```

or

```
class Bar implements Foo {
    prop = 1 as const;
}
```

====

In your class, `1` is being inferred as the widened `number` type because it would be strange to infer a mutable identifier to only be able to take that one exact initial value.  In your interface, you're not inferring the type, you're explicitly annotating it (unavoidably).

Try casting `prop = 1 as 1` or annotating `prop : 1 | 2 | 3 = 1` or make `type oneThroughThree = 1 | 2 | 3;` and use that alias to annotate both places.  Best yet, use an numerical enum to cover your range of acceptable values and perhaps be more readable.

Comment: This is confusing behavior. I specified that my class implements interface. In this interface I clearly described what types and properties I want to have. Then in the class that implements this interface, I get different types (in this example, the expanded number).

I understand how type widening works in the following example:


`const numericLiteral = 42; let widenedNumericLiteral = numericLiteral;`


But why do I have type widening in the class that implements the interface?

Comment: Maybe for the general case of a class implementing multiple interfaces, intersecting them to decide how to extend the type inference of the class members in that way hasn't been tackled yet as too complex?  I don't know.  Maybe request the feature on github and at least get a rationale (or a dupe tag).

Answer (score 0):

You need to also define the element in `Bar` since `Foo` is an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  prop: 0 | 1 | 2;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  prop: 0 | 1 | 2 = 1;
}
```

An interface just describes how a class needs to look, so basically you then need to re-define everything within the class to match your interface.

If you don't want to re-define the definition of the element a class might be a better option:

```
class Foo {
  protected prop: 0 | 1 | 2;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  public test() {
    this.prop = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can fix it this way. But why should I explicitly specify the type?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have assigned prop to be either type '0', '1' or '2' instead of being possible values of 0, 1 and 2

The proper way is to create an enum type variable with possible values of 0, 1 and 2 (e.g. enum values) and assign prop to assume the enum type values (e.g. prop: values)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html